# Storing images' URLs from firebase storage into firebase database - URLs are getting lost in cyberspace

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, async-await, firebase-storage

It's a React app with Redux. A form collects a new recipe data from user. The data may include an array of file objects (images) selected by user for upload. I call it `imagesToAdd`. An action is called `startAddRecipe`. The following needs to happen:

1. Write new recipe to firebase database - this returns a `ref.key` needed for storing images in storage. - this works ok
2. If there are `imagesToAdd` a function `uploadImages` is called that uploads images to firebase storage and returns an array with uploaded images URLs. this works ok
3. Now the recipe created in (1.) above needs to be updated with the URLs obtained in (2.) - this does NOT work. `console.log`s are showing the URLs alright but they are not appearing in firebase database:

```
images
  imageNames
    0: "voteUpSmiley.png"
  (no imageUrls)
```

...nor in the Redux store:

```
      images: {
        imageNames: [
          'voteUpSmiley.png'
        ],
        imageUrls: []
      },
```

Oddly the redux-logger tool shows the data ok in console:

```
    images:
      imageNames: ["voteUpSmiley.png"]
      imageUrls: ["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mniam-…=media&token=0e9b7991-0314-4f24-a94a-6b24f93baed7"]
```

The function `uploadImages` contains asynchronous tasks - firebase storage upload and a call for URLs so I `await` for the result and am getting correct one but it's not passed in time to subsequent statements because as said before the firebase database and the redux store are not getting the URLs. I've been looking at this for 2 days and seem to be going in circles.

I include the relevant code below for good people caring to have a look at it. Thank you.

```
export const startAddRecipe = (recipeData = {}) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {
      authorEmail = '',
      brief= '',
      createdAt = 0,
      ingredients = { general: [] },
      keyWords = [], 
      preparation = { general: [] },
      publishedAt = 0,
      shared = false,
      tips = '',
      title = '',
      votes = {
        downs: [],
        ups: [],
      },
      imagesToAdd = [],
    } = recipeData

    let imageNames = []
    imagesToAdd.map(image => {
      imageNames.push(image.name)
    })

    let recipe = { 
      authorEmail, 
      brief,
      createdAt,
      images: {
        imageNames,
        imageUrls: [],
      },
      ingredients,
      keyWords,
      preparation,
      publishedAt,
      shared, 
      tips,
      title,
      votes,
    }
    
    console.log('recipeB4', recipe); //this is showing URLs even before image upload???

    database.ref(`recipes/`).push(recipe).then((ref) => {
      console.log('ref.key:', ref.key);
      if (imagesToAdd.length > 0) {
        (async () => {
          recipe.images.imageUrls = await uploadImages(ref.key, imagesToAdd)
          console.log('recipeAfterImageUpload', recipe); // URLS are shown here but not reflected in the next line
          database.ref(`recipes/${ref.key}`).update(recipe).then(() => {
            console.log('RECIPE ADDED & UPDATED');
          })
        })()
      }

      dispatch(addRecipe({
        id: ref.key,
        ...recipe,
      }))
      dispatch(startSetRecipeKeyWords())
    })
  }
}
```

```
const uploadImages = (id, imagesToAdd) => {
  let imageUrls = []

  imagesToAdd.map(image => {
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`/recipePics/${id}/${image.name}`).put(image)

    uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
    (snapShot) => {
      // console.log(snapShot)
    }, 
    (err) => {
      // console.log(err)
    }, 
    () => {
      storage.ref(`recipePics/${id}`).child(image.name).getDownloadURL()
      .then(fireBaseUrl => {
        console.log('fireBaseUrl', fireBaseUrl)
        imageUrls.push(fireBaseUrl)
      })
    })
  })

  return imageUrls
}
```